# Why does my custom DataSource getConnection() throw "SQLException: The url cannot be null"?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am writing a Spring Boot (Batch) application, that should exit with a specific exit code. A requirement is to return an exit code, when the database cannot be connected.

My approach is to handle this exception as early as possible by explicitly creating a `DataSource` bean, calling `getConnection()` and catch and throw a custom exception that implements `ExitCodeGenerator`. The configuration is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {
...
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProps() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
public DataSource customDataSource(DataSourceProperties props) {

    DataSource ds = props.initializeDataSourceBuilder().create().build();

    try {
        ds.getConnection();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new DBConnectionException(e); // implements ExitCodeGenerator interface
    }

    return ds;
}
...
}
```

I want to *reuse* as much of the Spring Boot Autoconfiguration as possible, thats why I use the `@ConfigurationProperties`. I do not know if this is the way to go.

A call on `DataSourceProperties.getUrl()` returns the configured url (from my properties file):

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:....
```

But why does Spring Boot throw this exception when I call `DataSource.getConnection()`:

```
java.sql.SQLException: The url cannot be null
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:649) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:308) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:?]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:?]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:735) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:?]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:?]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:?]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:?]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:?]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:?]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:?]
at com.foo.bar.BatchConfiguration.customDataSource(BatchConfiguration.java:xxx) [main/:?]
...
```

Or do you know some cleaner way of handling this situation?

Thanks

**Edit:** Spring Boot version is 1.5.4

Comment: Are you trying to introduce a fatal error that kills the application?

Comment: I try to detect a failed database connection as early as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is subtle and lies in the line

```
DataSource ds = props.initializeDataSourceBuilder().create().build();
```

The `create()` creates a new `DataSourceBuilder` and erases the preconfigured properties.

`props.initializeDataSourceBuilder()` already returns a `DataSourceBuilder` with all the properties (url, username etc.) set. So you only have to add new properties or directly `build()` it. So the solution is removing `create()`:

```
DataSource ds = props.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
```

In this context the `dataSourceProps()` method bean can be removed too.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you dont set any value to your Datasource.

`props.initializeDataSourceBuilder().create().build();` does not set the values of your properties to your datasource. It just creates and builds one.

Try to set your values manually by using the static `DataSourceBuilder`. You will get the values from your `dataSourceProps` bean like that:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {
...
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProps() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
public DataSource customDataSource(DataSourceProperties props) {

      DataSource ds = DataSourceBuilder.create()
            .driverClassName(dataSourceProps().getDriverClassName())
            .url(dataSourceProps().getUrl())
            .username(dataSourceProps().getUsername())
            .password(dataSourceProps().getPassword())
            .build();

    try {
        ds.getConnection();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new DBConnectionException(e); // implements ExitCodeGenerator interface
    }

    return ds;
}
...
}
```